# How do I create a query for A and ( B or C ) in Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

How should I create an eloquent query to select where A and (B or C)

```
$user->whereHas( 'roles', function( $query ) use( $role_slugs ){
    return $query->whereIn( 'slug', $role_slugs );
} )-> ???
```

The idea here is to add a search term that should search by email or name... (but it has to keep the role always

```
->orWhere( 'email', 'like', '%' . $search_term . '%' )
->orWhere( 'name', 'like', '%' . $search_term . '%' )->get();
```

The problem is that if I do this, it ignores the role slug. I need to be able to search within the results of the first part of the query.

I don't want to do something like:

```
$users = $user->whereHas( 'roles', function( $query ) use( $role_slugs ){
    return $query->whereIn( 'slug', $role_slugs );
} )->get();

return $users->filter( function( $user ) use( $search_term ){
    return ( substr_count( $search_term, $user->email ) > 0 ) || ( substr_count( $search_term, $user->name ) > 0 );
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic: where A **AND** (B **OR** C)

So, you should enclose the parenthesis in a closure function passed to the `where()`:

```
$users = User::query()
        ->whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($role_slugs) {
            return $query->whereIn('slug', $role_slugs);
        })
        ->where(function ($query) use ($search_term) {
            $query->where('email', 'like', '%' . $search_term . '%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search_term . '%');
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: Fantastic, it worked like a charm. Thank you very much